# move item to the front of the LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

The purpose of this method is to find a certain value in the list. If the value is found, the node containing the value is moved to the front of the list without creating or deleting new nodes. The below is what I have so far. I don't think the move node part is working. Any help is appreciated!

```
public boolean findMove(E e){
    Node previous=null;
    Node current=head;
    while(current !=null){
        if(e.equals(current.item)){
            previous.next=current.next;
            current.next=head;
            head=current;
            System.out.println("True");
            return true;
        }
        current=current.next;
    }
    System.out.println("False");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You're not updating `previous` in your loop.

Comment: @John Please try my answer if it works for you?

Comment: Is the `boolean` `return` absolutely necessary or could you throw a `NoSuchElementException`? That aspect hinders your ability to do this a very clean concise way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try this? It seems you were not updating `previous`.

```
public boolean findMove(E e){
    Node previous=head;
    Node current=head;
    while(current !=null){
        if(e.equals(current.item)){
            //Found the item
            previous.next=current.next;
            current.next=head;
            head=current;
            System.out.println("True");
            return true;
        }
        previous = current;
        current=current.next;
    }
    System.out.println("False");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You may need to verify the code for boundary conditions as well.  It may need some small changes here and there. Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Few issues with your code:

- In the loop, the reference to head is not stored anywhere. Assuming, head is the starting point, you shouldn't alter it. But inside the loop, since "current" is updated to point to the next node, head is no longer a valid starting point of the LinkedList.
- If you found the item in the first position (head node), then you shouldn't move it (check for previous = null).

With the above things try this:

```
public boolean findMove(E e){
    Node previous=null;
    Node current=head;
    Node headerNode = head;
    while(current !=null){
        if(e.equals(current.item) && previous != null){
            // Update the previous node to point to the next node
            previous.next=current.next;
            // Move the current node to point to the starting position
            current.next=headerNode;
            // Mark the current node as header node
            headerNode=current;

            System.out.println("True");
            return true;
        }
        // Not found - Update Previous to point the current node
        previous = current;
        current=current.next;
    }
    System.out.println("False");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `previous != null` condition? Please explain.

Comment: If the element being searched is the head node itself, then previous will still be `null`. Accessing `previous.next` will throw null pointer exception.

Comment: How about you make both `current` and `previous` point to `head` only?

Comment: That should work as well. Since that is a glitch only at the beginning of the LinkedList. But still the head node is not retained inside the loop. So, we need another method level varioable `Node headerNode = head; ` so that we can hop back to the header node.